# angular model should be text, but input type should be time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time, getter-setter

I have a model wich comes with time values as `text` like `10:00:00` which means `10:00 AM`. Now i need to be able to let the user changes these values, but it should not just be a `input type="text"`, cause it would be to hard to change the time for the `user` on IOS like that. And using `type="time"` doesn't work because then the model would need to be a date object.

Any ideas how i can make something userfriendly and keeping my stupid model format?

Comment: use `$parsers` and `$formatters` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: @Girafa thank you very much for the hint, was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

That was the right hint, thank you very much.
Here the solution for others..

```
mainModule.directive('stupidTimeConverter', function() {

var directive = {};
directive.restrict = 'A';
directive.require = 'ngModel';

directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

    // Formatters change how model values will appear in the view
    ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return moment(value, "HH:mm:ss").toDate();
    });

    // Parsers change how view values will be saved in the model
    ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return moment(value).format("HH:mm:ss");
    });

};
return directive;
});
```